# Sci-fi TV show sexy villainess 70s-80s

Tags: tv, character-identification, actors

I'm trying to remember the name of a TV actress who played a sexy villainess in a popular sci-fi TV show  of probably late 1970s to 1980s.

I'm thinking of something in the original Battlestar Galactica era, but  probably not that.

I can only remember that she was dark-haired and very attractive. The character was humanoid but not human.

The actress had an Italian name the same as her father a very well known TV actor himself.

I know that's not much to go on but she was a 'babe' and I'm sure there are still a few older fans out there.

Comment: My first thought was Jacqueline Pearce, as Servalan in Blakes 7, but I can't see many matching details, except for being dark haired.

Comment: May be Ornella Muti https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornella_Muti, https://www.pinterest.com/pin/669629038338269996/ ?

Comment: I was thinking Ornella Muti as well, but she wasn't a villianess in Flash Gordon (also movie, not TV show).

Comment: Where did you watch this show? US? UK? It might help narrow the search down a bit..

Comment: I thought of the early 80s US TV series _[V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(1984_TV_series))_ but the alien villainess, Diana, was played by Jane Badler, which isn't a particularly Italian name.

Comment: Ardaala (or the War Witch) from Buck Rogers?  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078579/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like it could be Pamela Hensley from Buck Rogers in the 25th Century: [IMDB - Pamela Hensley](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0002135/mediaviewer/rm1249495040/?context=default)

She played the mildly evil alien Princess Ardala.

Comment: Doesn't fit with the famous Italian father, though

Comment: @WolfieSmith I think there was only one famous "actress" in the 70s that fits that criteria. That being Nancy Sinatra who was mostly known for her singing career

Comment: Actually, after looking a various photos I now think I was thinking of Princess Ardala from BRit25C. Don't know how I came up with the Italian father thing. I can only imagine I was conflating two different woman. Sorry.

Comment: Conflated with Debrah Farentino (Earth 2, Eureka), once married to James Farentino (not father, but much older) ?

Comment: #DoscoJones Yes, I think that's right! Deborah Farentino makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

She doesn't fit roles wise but I can only think of [Elyssa Davalos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elyssa_Davalos)

Answer (score 0):

Just to fill in the list:

[**Meg Foster**](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/785244885037865336/) as Evil-Lyn from **[Masters of the Universe](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093507/)**
[image]